# Having two posible groups, how I can reference the non-matched group?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

I want to match this

```
##A##B##A##
##B##A##B##
```

But none of this

```
##A##A##A##
##A##A##B##
##A##B##B##
##B##A##A##
##B##B##A##
##B##B##B##
```

And not using this: `##A##B##A##|##B##A##B##`

---

My approach was `##((A)|(B))##?##\1##`, but don't know what to put in that `?`

I didn't know very well how to ask this question, but if you have something better, I will edit to it.

Comment: Are you sure this is in javascript? I'm aware there is no `\1` in JS regexps!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Well, `new RegExp(/##((A)|(B))##A##\1##/).test("##B##A##B##")` returns `true` as expected. And works well for all inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative look-ahead `(?!...)` like this:

```
/##(A|B)##(?!\1)[AB]##\1##/
```

**Explanation:**

```
##     : litteral "##"
(A|B)  : litteral "A" or "B" grouped as \1
##     : litteral "##"
(?!\1) : not \1 (doesn't consume from the input string so we need the following [AB])
[AB]   : litteral "A" or "B" (set)
##     : litteral "##"
\1     : the result of the group \1
##     : litteral "##"
```

**Example:**

```js
var tests = ["##A##B##A##","##B##A##B##","##A##A##A##","##A##A##B##","##A##B##B##","##B##A##A##","##B##B##A##","##B##B##B##"];

var regex = /##(A|B)##(?!\1)[AB]##\1##/;
tests.forEach(function(test) {
  console.log(test, " => ", regex.test(test));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Good luck next time ;)!

Comment: Wow!!! Awesome and really interesting logic there! Thanks for the solution, and specially for teaching this :)